# Ambiguous use of -CONSTANT resolved as -&CONSTANT()

Tags: perl

I'm trying to declare magic numbers as constants in my Perl scripts, as described in perlsub. However, I get warnings:

```
$ cat foo.perl
use warnings ; use strict ;
sub CONSTANT() { 5 }
print 7-CONSTANT,"\n" ;
$ perl foo.perl
Ambiguous use of -CONSTANT resolved as -&CONSTANT() at foo.perl line 3.
2
$
```

The warning goes away if I insert a space between the minus and the `CONSTANT`. It makes the expressions more airy than I'd like, but it works.

I'm curious, though: What is the ambiguity it's warning me about? I don't know any other way it could be parsed.

(Perl 5.10.1 from Debian "squeeze").

Comment: [Readonly](http://search.cpan.org/~sanko/Readonly-1.04/lib/Readonly.pm#Comparison_with_%22use_constant%22) is probably better alternative to constants.

Comment: @ikegami, Wouldn't that make Damian upset? :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, some background. Let's look at the following for a second:

```
$_ = -foo;
```

`-foo` is a string literal<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
$ perl -Mstrict -wE'say -foo;'
-foo
```

Except if a sub named `foo` has been declared.

```
$ perl -Mstrict -wE'sub foo { 123 } say -foo;'
Ambiguous use of -foo resolved as -&foo() at -e line 1.
-123
```

Now back to your question. The warning is wrong. A TERM (`7`) cannot be followed by another TERM, so `-` can't be the start of a string literal or a unary minus operator. It *must* be the subtraction operator, so *there is no ambiguity*.

This warning is still issued in 5.20.0<sup>[2]</sup>. I have filed a [bug report](https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=121700).

---

1. Look ma! No quotes!

   ```
   system(grep => ( -R, $pat, $qfn ));
   ```
2. Well, 5.20.0 isn't out yet, but we're in a code freeze running up to its release. This won't be fixed in 5.20.0.

Comment: Marvellous, so `=>` actually autoquotes at the raw lexical level, without regard to syntax? Looks so: `use strict; print "abc", length def => "\n` prints `abc3` without complaining ...

Comment: @Henning Makholm, A bareword followed by `=>` is autoquoted. Yes, this is done at the lexical level. (Where else?!) I don't know what you mean by "without regard to syntax".

Comment: x @ikegami: I had always understood that to mean that _after_ parsing, if the entire expression to the left of `=>` consisted of a bareword only, the error from "strict subs" would be suppressed. One lives and learns ...

Comment: @Henning Makholm, There are no barewords or `=>` after parsing. The whole point of parsing is to give meaning to symbols.

Comment: Um, that bug report you link doesn't seem to demonstrate the problem. It goes `say -foo`, where there _isn't_ any term in front of the minus/dash.

Answer (score 1):

mpapec's answer helpfully referenced [perldiag](http://search.cpan.org/%7Erjbs/perl-5.18.2/pod/perldiag.pod) (which I wasn't aware of) but quoted the wrong diagnostic. The one I'm actually getting is

> `Ambiguous use of -%s resolved as -&%s()`
>
> (S ambiguous) You wrote something like -foo, which might be the string "-foo", or a call to the function foo, negated. If you meant the string, just write "-foo". If you meant the function call, write -foo().

So apparently the point is that `-CONSTANT` is a valid bareword. I didn't know they could start with dashes.

I still don't really understand why that would give a warning here, given that (a) I'm using `strict subs` so obviously I'm not going to throw around barewords deliberately, and (b) even if I were, a bareword or string in this position would be a syntax error anyway.

**Edit:** As pointed out (more or less) by tobyink, it is not actually that `-CONSTANT` in itself is a bareword, but that `strict subs` still allows barewords after the unary minus operator. Apparently the lexer isn't context-aware enough to know that parsing `-CONSTANT` as an unary minus is not allowed in this context.

Still feels strange to me -- one would expect the effect of prototyping a sub with no arguments ought to be that I deliberately *forfeit using that name as a bareword*, no matter whether it happens to be as the operand to unary minus or in a different context.

Comment: Regarding (a), barewords beginning with a dash are allowed, even in a scope with strict subs. It's documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Symbolic-Unary-Operators). My own personal pet theory is that this was originally a bug resulting from the parsing of the file test operators (`-f`, `-d`, etc), but was discovered to be useful, so became a documented feature.

Comment: Regarding (b), yes `7 "-foo"` would be a syntax error because two values adjacent to each other require an operator between them. That's why the potentially ambiguous `-foo` is resolved to mean `- &foo()` in this case rather than `"-foo"`. However, there are other cases where `-foo` is far more ambiguous, such as `bar(-foo)`, so Perl always warns you about this ambiguity when it's encountered.

Comment: @tobyink: Actually what perlop seems to document is that an unary minus applied to an ordinary bareword will prefix the string with a minus sign. So, at least according to the documentation, `-foo` would parse as `-'foo'` and _evaluate_ to the string `"-foo"`.

Comment: This behavior of unary minus is not restricted to barewords; it applies to `$a="foo"; print -$a` too.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the cause or an effect, but subroutines that can be parametrised by a hash conventionally use parameter names starting with a dash. See, e.g. [CGI](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html):  `print $q->header( -type => 'image/gif' )`. That would have to mean that barewords starting with a dash get some special treatment.

Comment: @ikegami, `O::Deparse` gives both as `-'foo'`